# If I find a Microsoft Vulnerability do I get credit for reporting it directly to Microsoft?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

I know that if you discover a vulnerability in a open source product you have the option of fixing it yourself, creating a bug report or other methods to prove that you have contributed to the internet (read society if you like) as a whole in some way.

If I have found a vulnerability and submit it to Microsoft (and they have recognized it as such) is there a similar way I can prove that I indeed provided information.  If so what is this method: Email/link on Microsoft site/good guy letter.

To avoid this question become a discussion (and getting closed immediately) please limit your responses to the following criteria:

- Please assume responsible disclosure as defined:
  [Is there a “standard” to reporting security vulnerabilities that we can use?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34871/i-work-on-an-open-source-project-is-there-a-standard-to-reporting-security-vu) using @void_in 's answer
- Please no ethical discussions (while important, I am not asking here)
- If it helps you frame the question this would be in regard to proof for a resume/CV
- Timing is not an issue.  I would assume that nothing would happen until at least a patch Tuesday update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Microsoft's policy seems to be that if you report the vulnerability to them responsibly, you'll get a mention in the [acknowledgments section of security bulletins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/gg309157.aspx). I would also expect some back and forth correspondence on the issue that you could keep as further proof.

> When you see a security professional acknowledged in a Microsoft
>   Security Bulletin, it means that they reported the vulnerability to us
>   confidentially, worked with us to develop the patch, and helped us
>   disseminate information about it once the threat was eliminated. They
>   minimized the threat to customers everywhere by ensuring that
>   Microsoft could fix the problem before malicious users even knew it
>   existed.

The acknowledgements section does indeed include considerable detail, naming individuals and organizations. For example, the [October 2013 bulletin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-oct) mentions (among others):

- xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com, working with HP's Zero Day Initiative, for reporting the Internet Explorer Memory Corruption Vulnerability (CVE-2013-3872)

It would certainly look very good on your CV!